# Change the color of different values within a variable in ggplot

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

I am working on a ggplot that shows the time from a surgery until a patient is able to move around. I want each value of "mobility_categories" to be a distinct color. Here is my code:

```
DiabetesAndCRC3_only_rectal %>% 
    filter(!is.na(mobility_categories)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=factor(mobility_categories), group = Diabetes_status)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(prop)),
             stat="count", width = 0.8) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(after_stat(prop)), y= after_stat(prop)),
              stat= "count", vjust = -.5)+
    facet_grid(~Diabetes_status) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,0.5))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKQGf.png)

The data is grouped by "Diabetes_status" and I think this is why i'm having issues. Normally I would just use scale_fill_manual, but this is not working.

Data:

```
structure(list(mobility_categories = c(">24", ">48", "<24", ">48", ">24", ">48", ">48", "<24", "<24", ">48", ">48", ">24", ">24", "<24", "<24", ">36", ">24", ">48", "<24", ">36", ">48", "<24", ">48", ">24", "<24", NA, ">48", ">48", "<24", NA, "<24", ">24", ">48", ">24", "<24", ">48", ">24", ">24", ">24", ">36) Diabetes_status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("Normal HbA1c", "High HbA1c", "T2D"), class = "factor"))
```

Comment: Please make this question reproducible by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(DiabetesAndCRC3_only_rectal)`.

Comment: structure(list(mobility_categories = c(">24", ">48", "<24", ">48", 
">24", ">48", ">48", "<24", "<24", ">48", ">48", ">24", ">24", 
"<24", "<24", ">36", ">24", ">48", "<24", ">36", ">48", "<24", 
">48", ">24", "<24", NA, ">48", ">48", "<24", NA, "<24", ">24", 
">48", ">24", "<24", ">48", ">24", ">24", ">24", ">36)
Diabetes_status = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("Normal HbA1c", "High HbA1c", "T2D"), class = "factor"))

Comment: Please double check your data, because it turns out that length of `mobility_categories` is 40, whereas length of `Diabetes_status` is 43.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I just provided a small part of the data. I have 193 observations in the dataset. I should probably have counted the data before posting to ensure that there were an equal amount of datapoints in each variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion how we can do it. The difference is that we calculate the proportions before:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

df <- structure(list(mobility_categories = c(">24", ">48", "<24", ">48", 
                                             ">24", ">48", ">48", "<24", "<24", ">48", ">48", ">24", ">24", 
                                             "<24", "<24", ">36", ">24", ">48", "<24", ">36", ">48", "<24", 
                                             ">48", ">24", "<24", NA, ">48", ">48", "<24", NA, "<24", ">24", 
                                             ">48", ">24", "<24", ">48", ">24", ">24", ">24", ">36"), 
                     Diabetes_status = c("High HbA1c", "T2D", "T2D", "Normal HbA1c", 
                                         "T2D", "Normal HbA1c", "T2D", "High HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c", 
                                         "High HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c", "T2D", "Normal HbA1c", 
                                         "High HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c", "T2D", "Normal HbA1c", 
                                         "High HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c", "T2D", "Normal HbA1c", "T2D", "High HbA1c", 
                                         "T2D", "High HbA1c", "High HbA1c", "T2D", "High HbA1c", "High HbA1c", 
                                         "T2D", "T2D", "Normal HbA1c", "High HbA1c", "High HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c", 
                                         "High HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c", "Normal HbA1c")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))

df_summary <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(mobility_categories)) %>%
  group_by(Diabetes_status, mobility_categories) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Diabetes_status) %>%
  mutate(prop = count/sum(count))

ggplot(df_summary, aes(x = mobility_categories, y = prop, fill = mobility_categories)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Diabetes_status, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(">24" = "red", ">48" = "blue", "<24" = "green", ">36" = "orange"))
```

[image]